# OpenGL Textures: Texture contains color lines when object is further away that some distance

Tags: opengl, shaders, textures

I tried searching on the web but couldn't find a reason for this. When I render an object close to the camera, the object and texture renders fine. But further away from a fixed distance, it starts showing weird color lines on the texture.

Close to the camera, no lines:

[image]

Further away, color lines appear on texture:

[image]

My shaders are pretty simple.

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 tex;

uniform mat4 projMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

out vec2 uvCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projMatrix * viewMatrix * vec4(pos.xyz, 1.0f);
    uvCoord = tex;
}
```

---

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

in vec2 uvCoord;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture1, uvCoord);
}
```

My texture parameters are:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I have generated mipmaps using `glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`

Comment: Try turning mipmapping on

Comment: @Bálint I have. `glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`

Comment: You aren't using them. Put "GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR" as the min filter

Comment: @Bálint, that looks like an answer to me. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually use the generated mip maps. You need to pass `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` (or any of the 3 alternatives) as the third argument when setting the min filter.